# Rank Values of one column by filtering on 2nd column in DAX

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to use the RANKX formula rank the values of one column, but filtered for the value of a second column.  In this example, col2 is a simple counter running in ascending value.  I'm trying to find item_id's Rank value relative to the col1.

```
col1    col2
1001    8001
1001    8002
1002    8003
1002    8004
1002    8005
```

I'd like to figure out a col3 that would read:

```
col1    col2    col3
1001    8001    1
1001    8002    2
1002    8003    1
1002    8004    2
1002    8005    3
```

Because that would be the rank of col2 relative to col1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use RANKX at all. See the section on EARLIER in the superb http://www.daxpatterns.com/. Add a new calculated column in your table:

```
=
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        MyTable,
        [col2] <= EARLIER ( [col2] )
            && [col1] = EARLIER ( [col1] )
    )
)
```

If you do want to use RANKX you can adapt the formula as follows:

```
=
RANKX (
    FILTER ( MyTable, [col1] >= EARLIER ( [col1] ) ),
    [Col2],
    ,
    1
)
```

Comment: Thanks Rory!  Both solutions worked beautifully, but the first looked to be a little more efficient resource wise so I went with that.  Excellent recommendation on the link as well.